# Getting even more users

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We've got a great site here, but we're only getting one or two posts a day at the moment, and it would be good to expand, especially given the new year.

How can we encourage more people to post here at Coffee.SE?

Comment: You seem to be under the misconception that low-traffic is a reason for site closure. [This is not the case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites/).

Comment: Well, one of the reasons is low-traffic. Our stats are also bad as well.

Comment: "If a public beta site does not produce consistently helpful content, and lacks the caretakers needed for flags and spam to get handled and our Be Nice policy to be upheld, it will be closed." - we are producing consistently helpful content, albeit slowly. We are fine.

Comment: Offer free coffee to new users? (**obvious sarcasm is obvious**)

Comment: We had a similar discussion back before the beta. Is there a way to dig that out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing that we can do is to expand on the agricultural side of coffee.  Most of the questions here are about the consumption side.